# limit node results to 10 in .map loop

Tags: reactjs

I would like to limit my results to 10 in the return below..

I'm not sure how to code it. I can't do it in the original graphQL API call as that fetches results for multiple displays (I need to grab everything then filter out what isn't needed)

```
 return (
   <Carousel 
                  activeIndex={index} 
                  onSelect={handleSelect} 
                
                    >

                    {finearts.nodes 
                        && finearts.nodes.map((arts) => (
                        imageQuery(arts) ?
                        
                        <Carousel.Item className="" key={arts.databaseId}>
                            
                            <Image src={arts.fineartfields.cloudlink} 
                                 alt={arts.featuredImage.node.altText} 
                                 className="carousel-image img-fluid shadow-sm"
                                  width={arts.featuredImage.node.mediaDetails.width}
                                  height={arts.featuredImage.node.mediaDetails.height}
                            />
                        </Carousel.Item>
      
                        : null  
                      ), [])}

                </Carousel> 
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use slice on finearts.nodes

finearts.nodes.slice(0,10) would return first 10 entries in the array which can be further chained to the map function; thus limiting map to be operated on only the first 10 entries of finearts.nodes array

Applying the suggestion to your code-

```
 return (
            <Carousel 
              activeIndex={index} 
              onSelect={handleSelect} 
            
                >

                {finearts.nodes 
                    && finearts.nodes.slice(0,10).map((arts) => (
                    imageQuery(arts) ?
                    
                    <Carousel.Item className="" key={arts.databaseId}>
                        
                        <Image src={arts.fineartfields.cloudlink} 
                             alt={arts.featuredImage.node.altText} 
                             className="carousel-image img-fluid shadow-sm"
                              width={arts.featuredImage.node.mediaDetails.width}
                              height={arts.featuredImage.node.mediaDetails.height}
                        />
                    </Carousel.Item>
  
                    : null  
                  ), [])}

            </Carousel>
```

)

Comment: thank you for responding. I realize i didn't give you enough info  imageQuery(arts) ? is a filtering condition, so if i add the slice to finearts.nodes it only grabs the first 10 results before the filter... in most cases returns to me 1 or 2 results.. the 10 needs to be 10 that meet imageQuery(arts) condition.. i hope I explained that well

Comment: we need to filter the data first and then use map with slice in that case; e.g. finearts.nodes.filter(arts => imageQuery(arts)).slice(0,10).map(...)

Comment: could we just not put a loop in the results that stops at 10?

Comment: I call it on another page as so... <MyCarousel 
        finearts={finearts} 
        imageQuery={(arts) => arts.fineartfields.fineseries === 'Figurative'} 
      />

Comment: in case we want to use a for loop and restrict the looping in the condition clause, we can do it before the return statement and push the nodes or maybe create DOM nodes and push to a temp array, which can be directly used in the JSX returned; reference- https://flaviocopes.com/react-how-to-loop/